# Maven Project Setup Stuck

Tags: maven

I am trying to create a maven project in eclipse, but it is getting stuck at 33%. Below is the console output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Progress (1): 2.5/14 kB
Progress (1): 2.9/14 kB
Progress (1): 1.4/14 kB
Progress (1): 1.4/14 kB
Progress (1): 1.4/14 kB
Progress (1): 1.4/14 kB
Progress (1): 1.4/14 kB
Progress (1): 1.4/14 kB
Progress (1): 0.2/14 kB
                       
Downloaded from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 41 kB/s)
```

That is all I am getting. Please help.

Comment: Do the intial build on plain command line and NOT inside Eclipse...

Comment: I don't see any error. I guess it's a network issue.